# Alternate model, which PK is used as default value for OneToOneRelation

Tags: python, django

I've run into a problem with Django migrations.

I have following models:

```py
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field_x = models.OneToOneField(
        'app_label.ModelB',
        default=ModelB.get_fresh,
    )

class ModelB(model.Model):
    field_y = models.TextField()
    
    @classmethod
    def get_fresh():
        return cls.objects.create().id
```

What I want to do is to add another field to ModelB.
So I've added the field and then runned makemigrations command.

```
class ModelB(model.Model):
    field_y = models.TextField()
    field_z = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    @classmethod
    def get_fresh():
        return cls.objects.create().id
```

Unfortunately, while running the tests, when django makes full migration for my project it says that there is no such column for default object.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "field_z" of relation "model_a_modelb" does not exist
```

Which is technically true, because default was added on previous migration and it don't know yet it new schema.
What I can do, to solve this problem and be able to extend ModelB in this case?